Is there any way to disable Excel's automatic addition of fully qualified references (absolute file path) to UDFs in xlam add-ins?
I have written several UDFs that I want to be able to use on multiple computers. To avoid copying these to every single computer every single time I add or improve one, my current solution is to store an .xlam on a network drive, and I've loaded said .xlam as an add-in to Excel on each computer.
The problem is that even though it's loaded as an add-in, Excel insists on appending the full file path to the xlam before the function name. (i.e., if I type "=MYFUNCTION", Excel will replace that with "='C:\Path\To\The\Xlam\custom_functions.xlam'!MYFUNCTION".
The results of this insertion are two-fold. First, it means I can't even open the file without Excel insisting it changed (so I'm guessing it refreshes the filepath upon opening?). This is super annoying, but not functionality-destroying.
But the second result comes if I use a UDF in an .xlsx that's stored on the network drive. Because the network drive path is different on different systems, Excel has effectively replaced my perfectly good relative reference with an absolute reference. When I try to open the .xlsx file on a different computer than the one on which it was last saved, Excel complains about external file references pointing to non-existent files.
I believe the second (and more serious) symptom could be worked around by creating a macro that finds and deletes the full qualification of the UDF name every time the file is opened. But I haven't tried it yet because that guarantees that the first symptom will be a permanent fixture: the file will change just because it's opened.
I read somewhere that if you use Name Manager to create a local variable that points to the add-in, it fixes the problem. However, this sadly just moves the problem out of the cell formula and into the Name Manager: Excel will still replace the reference to the add-in to its full file path.
At this point it's beginning to look like I will have to learn C+ so I can program .xll add-ins (because apparently they don't suffer the same problem).
Does anyone know why Excel does this? I don't see any difference in functionality between this and just using an external Excel file with UDFs, if I'm going to be stuck with the full file path in the formula anyway. What good is it to even load the .xlam as an add-in?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
